# Perform different operations depending on the parent activity?

Tags: android

I know how to get the intent that started the current activity, but how should I structure my code so that if user comes in from the login page one thing happens, and if they come from the signup page, another thing happens?

```
class Login extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "net.asdqwe.activities.Login.EXTRA_MESSAGE";

//code here

public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent sendLoggedInUserToHomePage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        sendLoggedInUserToHomePage.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,userEmailLoginPage);
        startActivity(sendLoggedInUserToHomePage);
    }

}


}
```

asd

```
class Signup extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.EXTRA_MESSAGE";

//code here

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent signupSuccessHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        signupSuccessHome.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, userEmail);
        startActivity(signupSuccessHome);
    }
}
```

And now we are in Home class and I dont know what to do.
Up until now, I had only the Signup page, so it was easy:

```
Intent loggedInUser = getIntent();
userEmailId = loggedInUser.getStringExtra(Signup.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
userInfo = dbTools.getUserInfo(userEmailId);
```

but how do I change this code now that I have users coming from Login as well?

Comment: Why not passing a value via intent to your Activity?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: Have a look a point 3 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: But I still dont understand how to sort through two incoming activities' sent items and how to create different actions for each case

Comment: pass a data like a string to your activity putString("before", "login") or putString("before", "signup") and handle these two options in your onCreate of the third Activity.

Comment: well im doing something similar. but the big question  is exactly how do i handle them and how do i know where has the user came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below code in your home class

```
String reqFrom = "";

Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if (b != null) 
reqFrom = b.getString("reqFrom");

if(reqFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){
// some action
}
else {
// some other action
}
```

Add the below code in your login page.

```
Intent sendLoggedInUserToHomePage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
i.putExtra("reqFrom", "login");
startActivity(sendLoggedInUserToHomePage);
```

Comment: this looks promising. will try it out

Comment: this was exactly the way I suggested you 15mins ago

Comment: the code that I was supposed to put in Home class is what I needed mostly :). I voted up your comments

Comment: how can I add one more message (the user Email) and use it in the Home activity? just add one more putExtra("userEmail", userEmail)?